# How did the Community user end up editing an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, editing

I noticed an interesting string of comments on [an answer to a question about TrueCrypt and US Customs](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/3366/82), and I went to investigate to see who had made the edit to the answer that sparked off all the controversy.

When I reviewed [the revision history for that answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/3366/revisions), it appears as though the [Community user](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) made the edit:

[image: Revision history for answer, documenting Community user making a controversial edit.]

Is the Community user now also adding content to answers, or is there another explanation for what I'm seeing?

Comment: [It's alive!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skynet_%28Terminator%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an anonymous user that has suggested the edit. I don't know why I did that but it then seems to be me who has accepted this suggested edit. Since the user is anonymous, immo the Community User is used as the official user name.

Comment: This might be considered a minor bug in the SE software: as I understand it, [Community ♦](http://travel.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) is what the software defaults to when there's no user ID specified in the database, but in this case the default leaves a somewhat confusing impression.